# Two approaches to implementing REST API on Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I do REST API on Spring. Took a course in Spring Data Hibernate and found that it made the REST API the most time-consuming way.

When I added a new entity to the domain, I went through the following chain of objects:

1. Entity - domain object
2. DTO - for transmitting/receiving an object to/from a client
3. Mapper - to convert between Entity and DTO
4. Repository - for interacting with the database
5. RestController - for processing API requests
6. Service - service class for the object

The approximate chain of my actions was as follows:

1. RestController processes requests - receives DTO from the client (in case of creation of a new object)
2. Mapper in controller converts DTO to Entity
3. Service is called
4. Service accesses the Repository
5. Repository returns the result of execution (created by Entity)
6. Service returns Entity is created in RestController
7. RestController returns to the client an object of type ResponseEntity, where I put the body and response code.

As you can see a large chain of actions and a large number of objects.

But then I found out that if you use Spring Data REST, all this doesn't need all the API supplied by Spring from the box. In general, you only need to create an Entity and Repository.

It turns out that for typical CRUD-type operations, I wrote a lot of controllers and their methods in vain.

Questions:

- When should I use RestConroller, and when is Spring Data REST?
- Is it possible to combine two approaches for one Entity? It turns out that I was wasting my time writing for simple operations like creating, getting, saving, deleting controllers, it can be moved to Spring Data REST.
- Will I be able to implement some of the actions that I did in Spring Data Rest in RestConroller? Such as:
- Return an entity property value as id instead of object? I mean I have properties for entities that are entities themselves, for these fields I sometimes need to return their ID instead of the whole entity.
- Is there any way to control error handling? In RestController I have implemented the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler extension class and all errors wherever they occur in my RestController are handled in the same way in one place and I always know that all errors will return approximately the same response structure.
- Data validation will have to be hinged on the fact that it used to be validated on DTOs received from the client. Are there any nuances waiting for me in this regard?

I'm a little stumped on how to move forward. Give me your recommendations and thoughts on this. Push forward on what to use and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Spring Data REST can do for you is scaffolding of the plain repository to rest service. It is much faster, and in theory it should be flexible, but in practice it is hard to achieve something more than REST access to your repositories.

In production I've used Spring Data REST as a wrapper of the database - in a service/microservice architecture model you just wrap-up sometimes the core DB into such layer in order to achieve DB-agnostic Application. Then the services will apply the business logic on top of this wrapper and will provide API for the front-end.
On the other hand Spring Data Rest(SDR) is not suitable if you plan to use only these generated endpoints, because you need to customize the logic for fetching data and data manipulation into Repoitories/Services. You can combine both and use SDR for the "simple" entities, where you need only the basic CRUD over them, and for the complex entities to go with the standard approach, where you decouple the entity from the endopint and apply your custom business logic into the services. The downside of mixing up both strategies is that your app will be not consistent, and some "things" will happen out-of-the-box, which is very confusing for a new developer on this project.

It loooks wasted time and efforts to write these classes yourself, but it only because your app doesn' have a complex database and/or business logic yet.

In short - the "standard" way provides much bigger flexibility at the price of writing repetetive code in the beginning.

Comment: I have an example, what I should do: I have to do a complex object is called Report. It has strings associated with it. If only one row wasn't written report shouldn't be written and all row to. How are you think in that case, I should do my project using the "Standart" way?

Comment: This is an example where Spring Data Rest will be harder to configure. In your "@Service" you need to apply validation for the rows from the ReportLines list. If you log into the DB and do additional stuff while reading the lines you need to set all the workflow "@Transactional" in order not to pollute the DB with broken data. Otherwise if you can persist in bulk i could just do 1.validate 2. if validated=OK then reportRepository.saveAll() and configure Hibernate/JPA for batch persisting.

Answer (score 2):

You have much more control building the full stack on your own, you are using DTO's instead of returning the entity objects, you can combine repositories in your services and you can put your business logic on the service layer. If you are not doing anything of the above (and you don't expect to in the near future) there is no need for writing all that boilerplate yet over again, and that's when Spring Data REST comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question.

Spring Data Rest provides abstraction and takes a most of the implementation in its hand. This is helpful for small applications where the business logic resides at the repository layer. I would choose this for applications with simple straight forward business logic.

However if I need fine grained control (eg: transaction, AOP, unit testing, complex business decisions etc. ) at each of the layers as you mentioned which is most often needed for large scale applications I will prefer writing each of these layers.

There is no thumb rule.